# Decision tree on LaTeX

Tags: tikz-trees

I've made that tree, but I need to do some improvements and I don't know how.
First of all, I want to paint the squares, making them purple, and the letters white.
Second, I want to make the arrows purple to.
Third,the boxes with the massage "Thanos fica com a joia" in a darker purple and the boxes with the message "Thanos fica sem a joia" in a lighter purple.
Last, I need to be able to put the probabilities next to the squares, and I don't know how.

Thank you guys for your help

```
\usepackage{forest}% for version 1
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow'=0,
    draw,
    align=c,
    font=\sffamily,
    rounded corners,
    parent anchor=east,
    child anchor=west,
    edge path={%
      \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- ++(5pt,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    }
  },
  highlight/.style={
    thick,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries
  }
  [{Peter Quill \\ rouba a joia}
        [{Kree captura Quill}
        [{Quill foge sem a joia}]
     [{Quill foge com a joia}
        [{Quill tenta vender a joia}
         [{Luta com Ronan}
         [{Vence}
         [{Joia é entregue a Tropa Nova}
         [{Thanos consegue a joia}]
         ]
         [{Quill fica com a joia}
         [{Thanos vence}
         [{Thanos fica com a joia}]
         ]
         [{Quill vence}
         [{Thanos fica sem a joia}]
         ]
         ]
         [{Quill entrega a joia para Youndu}
         [{Youndu vence}
         [{Thanos fica sem a joia}]
         ]
         [{Thanos vence}]
         [{Thanos fica com a joia}]
         ]
         ]
         ]
         [{Perde}
         [{Thanos fica sem a joia}]
         ]
         ]
         [{Quill vende a joia}
         [{Thanos fica sem a joia}]
         ]
         ]
    [{Quill escapa}
      [{Quill fica com a joia}
      [{Quill vende a joia}]
      [{Quill vence}]
      [{Thanos vence}
      [{Thanos fica com a joia}]
      ]
      ]
      ]
        ]
      ]
        ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: First, add `fill=purple,text=white,edge=purple,` into your tree declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what document class you used so here's an example of what you can do:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}% for version 1
\tikzset{darkp/.style={fill=purple!50!black},
        lightp/.style={fill=purple!50}}
        
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow'=0,
    draw,
    align=c,
    font=\sffamily,
    rounded corners,
    fill=purple,
    text=white,
    edge=purple,
    parent anchor=east,
    child anchor=west,
    edge path={%
      \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- ++(5pt,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    }
  },
  highlight/.style={
    thick,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries
  }
  [{Peter Quill \\ rouba a joia}
        [{Kree captura Quill}
        [{Quill foge sem a joia}]
     [{Quill foge com a joia}
        [{Quill tenta vender a joia}
         [{Luta com Ronan}
         [{Vence}
         [{Joia é entregue a Tropa Nova}
         [{Thanos consegue a joia}]
         ]
         [{Quill fica com a joia}
         [{Thanos vence}
         [{Thanos fica com a joia},darkp]
         ]
         [{Quill vence}
         [{Thanos fica sem a joia},lightp]
         ]
         ]
         [{Quill entrega a joia para Youndu}
         [{Youndu vence}
         [{Thanos fica sem a joia},lightp]
         ]
         [{Thanos vence}]
         [{Thanos fica com a joia},darkp]
         ]
         ]
         ]
         [{Perde}
         [{Thanos fica sem a joia},lightp]
         ]
         ]
         [{Quill vende a joia}
         [{Thanos fica sem a joia},lightp]
         ]
         ]
    [{Quill escapa}
      [{Quill fica com a joia}
      [{Quill vende a joia}]
      [{Quill vence}]
      [{Thanos vence}
      [{Thanos fica com a joia},darkp]
      ]
      ]
      ]
        ]
      ]
        ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[draw,rounded corners=5pt,fill=purple,text=white,font=\sffamily,inner sep=6pt] at (10,8) {Another Event};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But can i paint some boxes in different colors?

Comment: It's done like this: `[{Thanos fica sem a joia},lightp]`, where `lightp` is a tikzset defined in teh preamble. Did you try my code?

Comment: It works now. Actually, my overleaf wasn't recompiling properly, i have to refresh the page. Thank you Seb

Comment: You're welcome. For your further questions, just think of giving the entire code, with the preamble, and especially the document class, which is sometimes important to find solutions.